# Append text to output of shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to do dig for huge number of IPs and write out put of the command in one single line(in the format of paloalto firewall commands) but my script gives response like below

```
servername.
ip-netmask 10.224.161.242
```

My requirement is: `set address <servername> ip-netmask <ip>`

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='ip_in.txt' # name of file with IPs to handle
nameserver='10.225.9.18' # nameserver to query

for ip in `cat $filename`
do

dig @$nameserver -x $ip +short
echo "ip-netmask $ip"

done
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ip in $(cat $filename)
do
  servername=$(dig $nameserver -x $ip +short | sed 's/\.$//')
  echo "set address $servername ip-netmask $ip"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Keith for the response. It worked with little tweek servername=$(dig @nameserver -x $ip +short | sed 's/\.$//')

Comment: yeah - sorry about that.